# Disable all clicks on page for a couple of seconds after a function is run

Tags: javascript

When the user clicks a div an image appears and then they click the image to hide it. What I'm trying to do is disable all clicks on the page after the div is clicked for a couple seconds so the user doesn't accidentally close the image while they're waiting for it to appear.

I'm using javascript to show/hide the image

```
function showCard(ele) {
          var id = ele.id;
          var x = document.getElementById(id);
          var y = document.getElementById("cards");    


          if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";  
            y.style.display = "block";  

            } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
            y.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

I've done this before for a button but I'm not really sure how to disable the click when it's not a button.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Use setTimeout in Jquery for that

Comment: Most common practice is create a 100% w/h div to block page clicking elements, then after a couple of seconds you can destroy it with a setTimeout function

Comment: Also think about using classList.toggle instead of changing display

Comment: @David I don't know why I didn't think of this and now I feel dumb...

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean variable on the click handlers that you want to disable. 
And then check the variable to check if it will be possible to click or not.
Like in the example below, were you can only click once a second in the red box to change its color.

```js
let allowClicks = true;

document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 if(allowClicks) {
   e.target.style.background = e.target.style.background === 'red' ? 'blue' : 'red';
    allowClicks = false;
   setTimeout( () => allowClicks = true ,  1000 );
  } 
});
```

```css
html, body, #blo {
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="background: red"></div>
```